# how to boot to another os after fully booting in to ubuntu

Tags: boot

So how do when I fully booted up Ubuntu system boot to another OS without turning off the system.
Note, I want something like when a firmware (I forget which one does this) boots to user space with a TUI and then changes to boot to a different OS.

Comment: Not possible. What do you need this for?

Comment: First, why is it not possible, and to be able to boot an OS to ram and have it flash all partitions with an OS update

Comment: Which OS do you want to control the hardware? where do you want the other OS to reside meanwhile? How do you keep the controlling OS from overriding the other one?

Comment: Unless you just want to reboot, while setting some UEFI flag to boot into a different install automatically. That will "shut down the system" in the sense that the current OS will be completely shut down, but the hardware stays powered on (at least some of it does)

Comment: Transition from one OS to a different OS requires one to relinquish control (called "shutting down") before the other OS can take control (called "booting"). Computer operating systems are not currently designed to *share* control of hardware. Ubuntu is Open Source -- you can contribute the necessary code, if you wish.

Comment: If you need to run 2 OSes at the same time on one machine, you will need a [Type 1 Hypervisor](https://www.ibm.com/uk-en/cloud/learn/hypervisors), which runs as an OS whose sole purpose is to run virtual machines. You would then run your OSes as virtual machines inside the hypervisor, although not having the overhead of a full OS under the VMs helps a bit.

Comment: Do you want the other OS to run on top of Ubuntu? That's what virtual machines do. VirtualBox is in Ubuntu repositories and will allow you to run another OS while the host OS is still running.

Comment: You can use virtual installs and have them all booted.

Comment: not exaly what i was going for so like i sed there was firmware (that runs linux and was made by ibm) that booted into a different os while being in the user space thats what i am going for

Comment: You sure it wasn't a VM that it booted? or that it didn't shut down before booting the other OS? because short of you remembering which linux-based firmware (?!) this is, we can't really help. If all you need is to be able to access the Linux install while you're booted into the PC, try a Live USB maybe?

Comment: no it did not run a vm it was firmware bios uefi stuff it boot in to N bootable device because it was a bios

Comment: Firmware is capable of many things an OS isn't able to do. If your firmware doesn't do this, you're out of luck.

Comment: ok still can i boot to a different kernel from a booted ubuntu os

Comment: @mchid did you read my question?

Comment: if you meant something like [LinuxBoot](https://www.linuxboot.org/) then it relinquishes control once you boot another OS. If all you want is to reboot into another OS without hitting the power button, try [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43226/517866)

Comment: The correct solution depends on what you want to accomplish, as the thing you asked for isn't doable. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1412811/edit) your question to make it *clear* what you want to accomplish with this, so we can help you reach a workable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in short, the answer is `kexec` and as the [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Kexec) says run

```
# kexec -l path-to-vmlinuz --initrd=/boot/path-to-initramfs --reuse-cmdline
# systemctl kexec
```

To boot in to a different OS from a booted OS.
Note you also need to install `kexec-tools` with apt